# SAS filling rows

Tags: sas

```
data have;
infile cards missover;
input scrssn :$11. year FIPS :$5.;
cards;
111-22-3333 2008 
111-22-3333 2009 
111-22-3333 2010 09990
111-22-3333 2011 
111-22-3333 2012 08880
111-22-3333 2013 
111-22-3333 2014 
333-44-5555 2009 
333-44-5555 2010 67897
333-44-5555 2011 
333-44-5555 2012 56789
333-44-5555 2013 
333-44-5555 2014 67899
333-44-5555 2015
333-44-5555 2016
333-44-5555 2017
333-44-5555 2018
;
run;
```

i would like the data

```
111-22-3333 2008 
111-22-3333 2009 
111-22-3333 2010 09990
111-22-3333 2011 09990
111-22-3333 2012 08880
111-22-3333 2013 
111-22-3333 2014 
333-44-5555 2009 
333-44-5555 2010 67897
333-44-5555 2011 67897
333-44-5555 2012 56789
333-44-5555 2013 56789
333-44-5555 2014 67899
333-44-5555 2015
333-44-5555 2016
333-44-5555 2017
333-44-5555 2018
```

For each scrssn, I would like to fill the subsequent FIPS with the previous FIPS , but stop at the last row with available FIPS

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Is there anything you have tried so far, where you encountered a specific problem? It is appreciated if you show the attempt of solving your problem instead of just stating a task to be done. Some code to start on might help.

Answer (score 1):

First find out where the last non missing value is for this group. Then carry forward the previous value, but only up to the point of the last non missing value.

```
data want ;
  do _n_=1 by 1 until (last.scrssn) ;
    set have;
    by scrssn ;
    if fips ne . then lastfips=_n_ ;
  end;
  do _n_=1 by 1 until (last.scrssn) ;
    set have;
    by scrssn ;
    if fips = . and _n_ < lastfips then fips=previous;
    output;
    previous = fips;
  end;
  drop lastfips previous;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `retain` would do this...

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by scrssn ;

  length prevFIPS $5. ;
  retain prevFIPS '' ;

  if first.scrssn then call missing(prevFIPS) ;

  if not missing(FIPS) then prevFIPS = FIPS ;
  else                      FIPS     = prevFIPS ;
run ;
```

Comment: thanks chris, but this continues to fill after the last fips for each scrssn